# Train new data to pre-trained model

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning

Let's say I've trained my model and made my predictions.

My question is... How can I append some new data to my pre-trained model without retrain the model from the beginning.

Comment: Fine tune or use pre-trained weights

Comment: Thanks @Aditya but i don't want to predict on different dataset .... i want  to enrich my train dataset and then predict my results without retrain my train dataset from the beginning

Comment: Which algorithm? Are you using Scikit learn?

Comment: My question was not for a specific algorithm ......it was a general question.....why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a pre trained CNN classifier and apply it on a different image dataset](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28383/using-a-pre-trained-cnn-classifier-and-apply-it-on-a-different-image-dataset)

Comment: I think it matters which algorithm from which package. For instance, it seems to me that calling `fit` on a trained model in tf.keras updates the weights. This can be seen by a very low loss in the first epoch of the second call to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment yet. If you just load the model and use a fit method it will update the weights, not reinstance all the weights. It will just perform a number of weights update that you can chose, using the new data.

Comment: So @Louis you are telling me that if i load my pre-trained model and use a fit method with new data e.g ( loaded_model.fit(x_new_data, y_new_data) ) will update my model???

Comment: Yes, fit is not going to reset the weights, so you can do : load, compile, fit, save and you'll have trained your model a little bit more. You can also use train_on_batch to perform a single gradient update.

Comment: This is false, at least for sklearn. As per the [official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#refitting-and-updating-parameters), calling `fit()` more than once will overwrite what was learned by any previous `fit()`.

Comment: hey all... which is right ?... what `fit()` method do ?  update or overwrite from scratch ?

Comment: Calling fit more than once will overwrite the previous fit. See the SKlearn documentation.

Answer (score 14):

It all depends on the specific algorithm you're using. Some of them support incremental learning, while others don't.

For example, in the case of `scikit-learn`, using `fit()` more than once on the same model will simply overwrite the model's weights each time (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#refitting-and-updating-parameters) for more details).

What you can do however, is look for algorithms that implement the `partial_fit` api, and use this to retrain your existing models - see [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#incremental-learning) for a list of algorithms that support incremental learning and thus implement this api.

An alternative solution is to look for algorithms that support the `warm_start` parameter, e.g. [LogisticRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). Note that `warm_start` might also be influenced by other parameters, so you need to pay attention to their values, too - e.g. in the case of LogisticRegression, `warm_start` won't work if you use the `liblinear` solver (which is the default).

Answer (score 2):

I would say it depends upon the ML framework you are using. I have worked on Scikit and Tensorflow.

Both works in a different way.

**Scikit:**

1. partial_fit() is one way. If we call partial_fit() multiple times,
   framework will update the existing weights instead of
   re-initializing it again.
2. warm_state is another way which is provided by many algo. For
   example RandomForestRegressor(), it will add new estimators(new
   tress) which gets trained with new data we pass to it. Refer [Scikit
   link for more explanation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)

**Tensorflow**: Consider a basic TF code as mentioned below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
housing = fetch_california_housing()
m, n = housing.data.shape
target = housing.target.reshape(-1,1)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_housing_data = scaler.fit_transform(housing.data)
housing_data_plus_bias = np.c_[np.ones((m, 1)), scaled_housing_data]
n_epochs = 1000
learning_rate = 0.01
X = tf.placeholder(shape = (None, n+1), dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
y = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,1), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")
theta = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n + 1, 1], -1.0, 1.0, seed=42), name="theta")
y_pred = tf.matmul(X, theta, name="predictions")
error = y_pred - y
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error), name="mse")
gradients = 2/m * tf.matmul(tf.transpose(X), error)
training_op = tf.assign(theta, theta - learning_rate * gradients)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        fn,wights, loss, pred, op = sess.run((error, theta, mse, y_pred,training_op), feed_dict={X:housing_data_plus_bias, y:target})
        print(loss)
    best_theta = theta.eval()
    print(best_theta)
```

Consider I have trained and deployed this model(as a tf.saver() object). Now if I want to predict new values I have to feed my model with new **X values** and identify **"y_pred".**.
This process will not update my **theta**(weights) values(tensor graph, evaluate its dependent tensors only) and for prediction model will use existing **theta**.
In case I want to update **theta**, using the new samples, I have to evaluate **training_op**.

In this way we can improve TF model later with the new data.

Note: **training_op**, has a dependency on **theta** and **gradient**.